# Zoom URL-schema and deep link format for zoomus links

Tags: url-scheme, zoom-sdk, zoomus

I'm developing web application which uses Zoom API. In this application users are to be able to go to the specific Zoom meeting. Currently, we are using HTTPS-based links but Zoom provides very low-quality user experience with whose links. How to redirect users to `zoomus://` meetings? I found  [Zoom Documentation](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/additional-tips/launch-zoom-client-from-your-app/) such links exist. And found no information about format of those links.

So, the questions I have:

1. What is the format of `zoomus://` URL-schema links
2. What is the format of Zoom deep links
3. Is there any API which allows to get a direct Zoom app link for a meeting.

Comment: Also have this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When going via an HTTPS link the web browser then opens a zoommtg:// link which opens the Zoom app.  I've not found any documentation for the schema, but looking at the URLs they're of the form:

```
zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=<number>&pwd=<password>
```

Comment: I’m on iOS 16.6 and had to use zoomus://zoom.us instead of zoommtg